# How can I require a specific number of checked selectable options?

Tags: magento-1.7

I have a sample pack product that needs to require 5 different flavors chosen by the customer.

```
var maxCheckedCount = <?php echo $maxCheckedCount = $this->getProduct()->getMaxCheckedCount(); ?>+1;
var maxCheckedAlertMessage = "<?php echo $this->__('You have reached maximum allowed selections.'); ?>";

jQuery('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(){
    var n = jQuery('input:checked').length;
    if(n>=maxCheckedCount){
        jQuery(this).prop('checked',false);
        alert(maxCheckedAlertMessage);
    }
});
```

I added the above code to product/view.html to check get the maximum selectable options, and prevent any more. I am wondering how I  can check that the minimum selectable options are selected before allowing the item to be added to cart.

I have created a min_checked_count attribute along with the max_checked_count attribute from above, now I just need to know where to check against it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered this question initially from which you've taken the sample code here: [how I can limit the maximum selectable simple products?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5244/how-i-can-limit-the-maximum-selectable-simple-products).

The answer, really, is very easy. You will extend the `click` handler to check if the minimum number has been reached and then enable the Proceed to Checkout button:

```
var maxCheckedCount = <?php echo $maxCheckedCount = $this->getProduct()->getMaxCheckedCount(); ?>+1;
var maxCheckedAlertMessage = "<?php echo $this->__('You have reached maximum allowed selections.'); ?>";
var minRequired = 3; //this is your minimum value

//Disabling the checkout button on load
var $btnCheckout = jQuery('.btn-checkout')
$btnCheckout.attr('disabled','disabled');

jQuery('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(){
    var n = jQuery('input:checked').length;

    //check for minimal value, and enable the button
    if(n>=minRequired){
        $btnCheckout.removeAttr('disabled');
    }

    if(n>=maxCheckedCount){
        jQuery(this).prop('checked',false);
        alert(maxCheckedAlertMessage);
    }
});
```

Be aware that this only checks if the minimum has been reached when the checkbox is clicked. If for some reason you had the minimum number of checkboxes pre-checked on load you would have to modify the script to not disable the button by default.

Comment: I appreciate the speedy reply, and this worked perfectly! In case anyone else wants to use this, in my case I wanted to disable the Add to Cart button rather than the Checkout button. I simply replaced btn-checkout with btn-cart.

Comment: Is there an easy way to make sure this only disables the button on products with a required amount of selectable options? As it stands, this disables the add to cart button on all products even if they have no checkboxes.

Comment: I was able to check against the sku of the item using php `var sku = "<?php echo Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getSku(); ?>";
` `if (sku == "SKU-HERE") {

$btnCart.attr('disabled','disabled');
}` But still open to better ideas

Comment: I don't like sku-based inclusion lists. Rather add a body class to the page via an observer to check onload or check if there are checkboxes in a particular div before disabling.