# Limiting total qty of custom options and making checkboxes mutually excludable

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, custom-options

what I am trying to make is a make-your-own-pizza configurator.
Basically I have setup a simple product (the pizza) and I have added a variety of custom options as toppings. The problem is that there are around 10 toppings but I would like to limit the total amount a customer can pick to about 5 (the pizza won't bake really well with 10).

Since I didn't find such function in magento I used JS to do that. Basically once you select more than 5 checkboxes you receive the following message which works perfectly.
(I used this post: [how I can limit the maximum selectable simple products?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5244/how-i-can-limit-the-maximum-selectable-simple-products))

```
var maxCheckedCount = <? php echo $maxCheckedCount = $this - > getProduct() - > getMaxCheckedCount(); ?> +1;
 var maxCheckedAlertMessage = "<?php echo $this->__('You have reached maximum allowed selections.'); ?>";

 jQuery('input[type=checkbox]').click(function () {
     var n = jQuery('input:checked').length;
     if (n >= maxCheckedCount) {
         jQuery(this).prop('checked', false);
         alert(maxCheckedAlertMessage);
     }
 });
```

The difficult part, however is making the checkboxes mutually exclusive, for example, we have two checkboxes per topping: single and double. When I click double and I have selected single before that, I would like it to get unselected. I am not using radio buttons because I would like the customer to be able to unselect his choice without clicking anything else and I think it might conflict with the script above.

I've used the following code:

```
$("#idofsingle").click(function() {
        if($("#idofsingle").is(':checked')) {
            $("#idofdouble").prop('checked', false);
        }
    });
    $("#idofdouble").click(function() {
        if($("#idofdouble").is(':checked')) {
            $("#idofsingle").prop('checked', false);
        }
    });
```

It works alright in a simple environment but in magento I reckon it should pick the ID's of the checkboxes using php which I am not able to do. Any hints?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You should probably define a mapping - maybe just in your javascript for simplicity - to identify which custom options are mutually exclusive.

```
optionGroups = [
    [1, 2],
    [3, 5, 7]
]
```

Where those numbers correspond to the custom option IDs.  One thing to keep in mind though if you go that route is that, if you ever delete and recreate a custom option, the IDs will change, which can be a hassle.

Also keep in mind that if you try to go this route, you'll run into issues if you try to add these custom options to a different product, because those custom option instances will have different ID numbers.

Then, once you have this mapping, you can just loop over them in the `click()` event, and if one of the checkboxes in a group is selected, then unselect it.